# Where can i find buildRow parameter?

Tags: 8, entities

in [EntityListBuilder::buildRow](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/function/EntityListBuilder%3A%3AbuildRow/8.2.x) we can define row like below:

```
$row['title']['data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => $entity->label(),
    '#suffix' => ' ' . drupal_render($mark),
    '#url' => $uri,
  );
```

question is: where can i find list of the options/parameters documentation of this? (#type, #title, what is the other possible option?)

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the render element [Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Link.php/class/Link/8.3.x), which is used to make the title clickable. The non linked version would look like this:

```
$row['title'] = $entity->label();
```

You can use any [render element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.3.x) or a nested [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want to know about Render arrays in Drupal 8.

Generic properties that can be given for a render element can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays)

As mentioned in that page, every element of a type can have some specific properties which have to be figured out individually.

For Ex:  Element of type can have title, url while element of type markup can have #markup.